# Выражение "Пролететь, как фанера над Парижем"

Tags: фразеология

"Пролететь, как фанера над Парижем" - это современное выражение, но ведь и оно когда-то и откуда-то появилось в русском языке. Интересно, откуда оно взялось? Или составлено просто по принципу наибольшей абсурдности?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Версий много, все недостоверные. Вот одна.

*В 1908 году известный французский авиатор Огюст Фаньер, совершая показательный полет над Парижем, врезался в Эйфелеву башню и погиб. После чего известный меньшевик Мартов писал в «Искре», что «царский режим летит к своей гибели так же быстро, как г-н Фаньер над Парижем».*

Остальные версии - поисковики вам в помощь.
Одно могу сказать: подобные идиомы никогда не рождаются на принципе чистого абсурда.

Comment: Вряд ли. Не было в 1908 ни "Искры", ни лётчика Огюста Фаньера. Да и выражение появилось в 1970-х - кто бы помнил тогда французских лётчиков начала века?
Остальные версии тоже сомнительны. Связь с фильмом "Воздухоплаватель" весьма отдалённая, и фильм малоизвестный, это тебе не "Бриллиантовая рука".

Comment: @Игорь ну я же еще тогда написал, что ***все версии недостоверные***. Но вот есть развитие https://story.dirty.ru/kak-fanera-nad-parizhem-847872/  Про фильм - это не ко мне, но по моей ссылке  это тоже есть.